# Add episode to tvseries

Tags: java

So I am a student who just started with java and got this task.

''Make a class which represent an episode in a TVSeries. This should contain instance variables for episode, season, title and playtime. We would also make to constuctors to be able to create an episode, one with all the instance variables, and one without playtime (overloading).

Then make a class which represent a TVSeries. This should contain instance variables for title, description, release date and a list with episodes.

An episode shall be able to individually added via a methode addEpisodes(Episode theEpisode)''

So I have made the two classes (Episode with two constructors and TVSeries), but don't know what the addEpisodes(Episode theEpisode) methode shall contain. Would appreciate some help :)

```
public class TVSerie {

private String titel;
private String description;
private LocalDate releaseDate;
private ArrayList<Episode> listeWithEpisods;

public void addEpisode(Episode theEpisode) {
    ArrayList<Episode> listeWithEpisods = new ArrayList<>();
    listeWithEpisods.add(theEpisode);
    System.out.println(listeWithEpisods);
}

public class Episode extends TVSerie {
private int episodeNumber;
private int sesongNumber;
private String titel;
private int playtime;

public Episode(int episodeNumber, int sesongNumber, String titel, int playtime) {
    this.episodeNumber = episodeNumber;
    this.sesongNumber = sesongNumber;
    this.titel = titel;
    this.playtime = spilletid;
}

public Episode(int episodeNummer, int sesongNummer, String tittel) {
    this.episodeNumber = episodeNumber;
    this.sesongNumber = sesongNumber;
    this.titel = titel;
}
```

Comment: So post the code of your TvSeries and Episode classes, and how you store episodes in TvSeries, and how you would propose to add a new one, and explain what goes wrong when you try to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the assignment suggest, TVSeries should have List and addEpisode needs to add it to your list.

```
public class TVSerie {

private String titel;
private String description;
private LocalDate releaseDate;
private List<Episode> listeWithEpisods;

public TVSerie(){
    listeWithEpisods = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addEpisode(Episode theEpisode) {
    listeWithEpisods.add(theEpisode);
    System.out.println(listeWithEpisods);
}
```

You need to initialize your list only once, inside the constructor.
In your implementation every time `addEpisode` is used you create new instance of your episode list and therefore deletes the former one. 
In addition, Episode should not extends TVSerie, it is not a type of it. It is a type of it's own not related to TVSerie.

Comment: @Makoto I have updated the code so it will match your standards :)

Comment: (I would have preferred eager initialization but you can't read my mind....I'll withdraw my complaint, for now...)

Comment: Thanks, but to display/print the whole listWithEpisodes in a main.java, do you then have to first make a getter in TVSeries then make a for in main?

Comment: Exactly! You can try using forEach method to print the List elements.